# How to encrypt 30 digit number into 10 digit number?

Tags: encryption, numbers

Is possible encrypt 30 digit number into 10 digit number, i have number like

23456-32431-23233-76543-98756-54543   i need look like 10 digit encrypt format.

Comment: Well you can't, can you, unless  you start using letters and other characters. Base-64 for example. Or do you mean 'hash'?

Comment: Anything, i need compressed the digit.

Comment: For curiosity, how goo.gl & bit.ly working?

Comment: Err, by using letters and other characters? And 'encrypt' and 'hash' aren't the same thing, and you can't just use 'any' of them. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: What is your actual problem? How many numbers you have? Do you have at most 10^10 such number? if so one can do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible encrypt 30 digit number into 10 digit number,

Purely mathematically - you cannot. Still we are assuming you want to represent 30 decimal digits of any value using 10 decimal digits. You simply want to put a pint into a shot glass.

> Anything, i need compressed the digit.

Compression would be possible if some of the stated assumptions would be not valid.

If you could represent the output as text (any character or binary), you could encode the decimal value to binary/base64 form which would  allow shorten representation (still no to 1:3 ratio)

Compression would work well, if the input values (or part of the input) would not be random. If digits or significant part of the input have not uniform distribution or part of the input would represent a limited counter, then the parts or digits could be represented with limited number of bits.

You may know more about your data, so only you could tell anything about the data distribution.

> curiosity, how goo.gl & bit.ly working?

The "shortening" sites are a key-value storage, mapping a generated short value to stored full url. So it's mapping, not any compression.